# Fetch Xero Payments through Salesforce Apex

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to fetch Xero Payments using set of payment ids. But I'm getting all payments instead of getting particular payments.

```
thisRequest.setEndpoint('https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Payments?ids='+paymentIds);
```

in the paymenIds i'm having 2 for example.

If you have any idea pls suggest me in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property called ids in Payments.
You can specify any property with an s appended to get a list of Payments.
If you have the PaymentIds you would specify:

```
thisRequest.setEndpoint('https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Payments?PaymentIds='+paymentIds);
```

PaymentIds are Guids in Xero btw.

Assuming you have the invoice Ids for the payments you require you could do:

```
thisRequest.setEndpoint('https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Payments?References=INV-001,INV-002');
```

See https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/payments